# Concatenating a single equals sign to a string in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program for my class assignment and I am trying to concatenate a single equals sign '=' between two other strings.

What I have currently looks like this:

```
void print_csv(csv_line header, csv_line data) {
    int index;

    char first[MAX_CHARS];
    char second[MAX_CHARS];

    for(index = 0; index < header.nfields; index++) {
        strcpy(first, header.field[index]);
        strcpy(second, data.field[index]);
        printf("%s%s%s\n", first, " = ", second);
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

[image: First output]

However, when I change the code to have two equal signs or anything else for that matter like so:

```
printf("%s%s%s\n", first, " == ", second);
```

I get a much different output, which is much closer to what I need but with two equal signs instead of two:

[image: Second output]

So my question is, why is it printing so much more when I put something other than just one equals sign and how can I get it to only be one sign when still printing out everything as it should?

Comment: The posted code does not look like it could produce the second posted output.  Could you revise the code to make a minimal example (with main, and actual type declarations)?

Comment: There is nothing that can explain any error you report. The `printf` calls are both correct. Any error must thus be somewhere else. In particular, `data.field[index]` may be wrong as the code prints `< Col 4 = `

Comment: By specifying *%s*, the code for `printf`is going to interpret `first` and `second` as pointer arguments. That being said, your `printf` statement looks correct. So I strongly feel that @PaulOgilvie has hit the bull's eye. The preceding `strncpy` statements could be where your problems start. Could you give more detail about your `csv_line`?

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%s%s%s\n", first, " = ", second);
```

Instead of this why don't you just write this -

```
printf("%s = %s\n", first, second);
```

But if you want to append `=` to any of string use `sprintf` .

Comment: This would be an improvement, but I am missing how it answers the question.  (and I'm not really sure I understand the question).